# How to read a file and write to other file in tcl with replacing values

Tags: tcl

I have three files: Conf.txt, Temp1.txt and Temp2.txt. I have done regex to fetch some values from config.txt file. I want to place the values (Which are of same name in Temp1.txt and Temp2.txt) and create another two file say Temp1_new.txt and Temp2_new.txt.

For example: In config.txt I have a value say IP1 and the same name appears in Temp1.txt and Temp2.txt. I want to create files Temp1_new.txt and Temp2_new.txt replacing IP1 to say 192.X.X.X in Temp1.txt and Temp2.txt.

I appreciate if someone can help me with tcl code to do same.

Comment: Not really related to Tcl, but I've just came across a very interesting *general purpose* tool for making transformations of configuration files having arbitrary syntax -- [augeas](http://augeas.net/)

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the information provided, there basically are two ways to do what you want:

- File-semantics-aware;
- Brute-force.

The first way is to read the source file, [*parse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) it to produce certain structured in-memory representation of its content, then serialize this content to the new file after replacing the relevant value(s) in the produced representation.

Brute-force method means treating the contents of the source file as plain text (or a series of text strings) and running something like [`regsub`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/regsub.htm) or [`string replace`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M47) on this text to produce the new text which you then save to the new file.

The first way should generally be favoured, especially for complex cases as it removes any chance of replacing irrelevant bits of text.  The brute-force way me be simpler to code *(if there's no handy library to do this, see below)* and is therefore good for throw-away scripts.

Note that for certain file formats there are ready-made libraries which can be used to automate what you need.  For instance, [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) facilities of the [tdom](http://wiki.tcl.tk/tdom) package can be used to to manipulate XML files, INI-style file can be modified using the [appropriate library](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/ini.html) and so on.